# My developed stencil theme add in Theme Marketplace : Bigcommerce Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

I have developed new stencil theme.

So how can I add in Theme Marketplace in Bigcommerce ?

I don't want to share theme zip file to user.

If I add theme in theme marketplace then user can easily apply theme from theme marketplace of bigcommerce.

Can any body help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help you. :)

Please refer following article of Bigcommerce.

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/bundling-and-submitting-a-theme

Here, you will get all the information about submitting a theme and add in to Theme Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to add a theme to the theme marketplace for Stencil. You can use third party marketplaces to allow customers to find your theme and install it on BigCommerce, but the native marketplace is closed to select partners at this time.